# Microphone doesn't work!

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, microphone

So, I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and then after all Skype. But when I want to talk with someone my microphone actually get high. He is changing from Rear Microphone (that's is version who works) to Front Microphone (that's not working at all). What can I do to fix it guys?
Here is an image of the volume control:

[image]